# combining multi numpy arrays (images) in one array (image) in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I have some numpy arrays which its elements are pixels of 28*28 images like this:

[image]

25 of these arrays are in one array in shape of (25,28,28) or (5,5,28,28). Is there any efficient way to stack them to have  one image: 5*5 of 28*28 images.

[image]

I tried np.reshape to (140,140) array and plt.imgshow. But the output was a messed image.

Comment: Huh? How can you get 625 images of 28x28 in an array of 25x28x28?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I tried np.reshape to (140,140)..."*  That will work if you first transpose the input appropriately.

Suppose the input `x` has shape (5, 5, 28, 28).  To get the array `y` with shape (140, 140) that contains the images arranged the way you want, you can do:

```
xshp = x.shp
y = x.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape((xshp[0]*xshp[2], xshp[1]*xshp[3]))
```

If `x` *always* has shape (5, 5, 28, 28), you can hardcode the constant 140:

```
y = x.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape((140, 140))
```

For example, here I create `x` with shape (5, 5, 28, 28) where each 28x28 image is a constant.  The constants are chosen randomly.  The tranposed, reshaped array `y` is plotted, and you can see that all the constant blocks are arranged correctly.

```
In [148]: rng = np.random.default_rng()                                                                       

In [149]: x = np.repeat(rng.integers(0, 256, size=(5, 5)), 28*28, axis=-1).reshape((5, 5, 28, 28))            

In [150]: y = x.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape((140, 140))                                                   

In [151]: imshow(y)
```

[image: plot]